# per page product filter is not working on search page

Tags: woocommerce

I have added this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'selectbox', 20 );
function selectbox() {
$per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo '<div class="woocommerce-perpage">';
echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';
$orderby_options = array(
'12' => 'Per Page 12',
'24' => 'Per Page 24',
'36' => 'Per Page 36',
'48' => 'Per Page 48',
'60' => 'Per Page 60',
'72' => 'Per Page 72',
'84' => 'Per Page 84',
'96' => 'Per Page 96',
'3000' => 'All'
);
foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
echo "<option ".selected( $per_page, $value )." value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_products_query' );
function pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
$per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && !is_post_type_archive( 'post' )) {
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );
}
}
```

Everything is working on the shop and category page. But in the search results page, it is showing the filter but it's redirecting to https://example.com/?perpage=36. But it should be https://example.com/?s=screw&post_type=product&?perpage=36.Seeking help from you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Here is the final code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'jowelr_selectbox', 20 );
function jowelr_selectbox() {
$per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo '<div class="woocommerce-perpage">';
echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) document.location.href=this.value">';
$orderby_options = array(
'12' => 'Per Page 12',
'24' => 'Per Page 24',
'36' => 'Per Page 36',
'48' => 'Per Page 48',
'60' => 'Per Page 60',
'72' => 'Per Page 72',
'84' => 'Per Page 84',
'96' => 'Per Page 96',
'3000' => 'All'
);
if(is_search()) {
    foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
echo "<option ".selected( $per_page, $value )." value='?s=". get_search_query(true)."&post_type=product&perpage=$value'>$label</option>";

}
}
else {
foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
echo "<option ".selected( $per_page, $value )." value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";
}
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'jowelr_pre_get_products_query' );
function jowelr_pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
$per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && !is_post_type_archive( 'post' )) {
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );
}
}
```